# Firebase library for Node.js breaks when using 'babel' loader. Specifically: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I'm building an app with ReactJS, Webpack, Babel, and Firebase.

When I run webpack to bundle my code using the babel loader, I see the following is printed out amongst many other lines:

> [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of
>   "/Users/.../myproject/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-web.js"
>   as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

Then when I try and require('firebase') in my app, and then run it in the browser... the browser prints out the following in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
(anonymous function) @ firebase-web.js:12
(anonymous function) @ firebase-web.js:262
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap da2fff1ce4ea892319dc:19
aa @ PlayerStore.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap da2fff1ce4ea892319dc:19
prop @ Player.js:19
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap da2fff1ce4ea892319dc:19
(anonymous function) @ index.js:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap da2fff1ce4ea892319dc:19
obj.__esModule.default @ bootstrap da2fff1ce4ea892319dc:39
(anonymous function) @ bootstrap da2fff1ce4ea892319dc:39
```

PlayerStore.js:3 is where I have the line:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error when I try and load my app? I'm not sure if this error started because I switched from using jsx-loader in Webpack to babel, or because I ran 'npm update' and the new version of one of the packages I'm using is breaking things.

Comment: That's weird.  Can you make sure you're using the latest version of Firebase?  It's had some recent fixes that might affect this.  Else, it'd be helpful if you could look at the code and see what object it's looking for 'navigator' on (or else put your app online somewhere so we can look at the problem).  In general it's odd that 'navigator' is not defined.  I'd more expect to see that sort of error if you were using Firebase in node.js or something.  Presumably it's looking for window.navigator which should be defined in a browser!

Comment: I think the problem has to do with that BABEL line. In node_modules my firebase package is 2.2.7. If instead of using the require('firebase') line I just directly put the script tags to pull from firebase cdn in my index.html, then my app works fine. So something with who webpack is packaging firebase I think is breaking it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webpack + Firebase: Disable parsing of Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221357/webpack-firebase-disable-parsing-of-firebase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be your answer: [Webpack + Firebase: Disable parsing of Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221357/webpack-firebase-disable-parsing-of-firebase)

Babel adds `"use strict"` which causes `this` to be undefined.

Solution would be to disable babel-loader for firebase, as described in the linked answer:

```
...
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
  ]
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this Firebase issue on ionic 3 with webpack, add this to the default [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js):

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_TRANSPILE_LOADER,
    exclude: /node_modules/  // <-- add this 
  }
```