# Webpack + Firebase: Disable parsing of Firebase

Tags: firebase, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am working on a web app that uses Webpack to bundle modules.  For whatever reason, the introduction of Firebase into the app is causing Webpack to throw an error.  This error is occurring when Webpack attempts to load the Firebase module.

How do I go about excluding Firebase from Webpack, but can still call

`import Firebase from 'firebase';`

from within my JS files?

Here are some screenshots of the error.

[pic1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B34VIyGG1u-uZndIRVo2MkluU2M/view?usp=sharing)
[pic2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B34VIyGG1u-uMFNOYnc0bzBONGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It might expect global context. It's hard to say exactly without checking out Firebase code. See https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#imports-loader for one way to deal with it.

Answer (score 23):

**tl;dr** Exclude `/node_modules/` from the babel-loader paths.

---

Your 2nd pic shows the error on `firebase-web.js:12`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
```

Unfortunately, [firebase-web.js is minified](https://gist.github.com/elliottsj/4d9ed932a64548cca3c0#file-firebase-web-js), so it's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong. Let's [beautify firebase-web.js](https://gist.github.com/elliottsj/4d9ed932a64548cca3c0#file-firebase-web-beautified-js) using http://jsbeautifier.org:

[image: TypeError in beautified firebase-web.js]

Now it's plain to see that the script is trying to access `aa.navigator`, but `aa` is undefined. You can see [at the top of the file](https://gist.github.com/elliottsj/4d9ed932a64548cca3c0#file-firebase-web-beautified-js-L4):

```
var h, aa = this;
```

We can see what the script is trying to do now: it expects `this === window` so it can access [`window.navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator).

But why is `this` undefined? It's because, at some point, the script is being put into [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript), which causes `this === undefined` instead of `this === window`. We can see that in the webpack-generated *main.js*:

[image: "use strict" in main.js]

It turns out that the `"use strict"` is being prepended by [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), so we should be able to disable babel-loader for *firebase-web.js* to solve the problem:

```js
...
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
  ]
}
...
```

[image: firebase-web.js without babel-loader]

Good, now there's no more `"use strict"` and the error no longer occurs!

(Full disclosure: I worked on the same project that @kashiB is working on and have access to the source code.)

Comment: Thank you so much ... I have spending a week trying to figure out the error on window.navigator, on a another context but with babel. great !!

Comment: The **tl;dr** comment is what helped me. Turns out, I was doing this: `exclude: '/node_modules/'`. I removed the quotes and everything started working. Now only if I could get those 3 days back!

Comment: I was using rollup and `exclude: '/node_modules/**'` alone did not fix the issue. I had to add `useStrict: false` to my rollup config also

Comment: @lukejacksonn `'/node_modules/**'` is wrong. The slashes are the JS delimiters of a RegEx expression. If you add quotation marks (`'`) you turn it into a regular string. `'node_modules'` on the other hand should work as well as `/node_modules/` does.

Comment: I am a babel noob. I am working on a react-native project, what file I am placing this in?

Comment: react-native does not use webpack

Comment: I hope everyone realizes `import Firebase from 'firebase';` is not es6, just yet another Angular trap. There are two errors: import does not take a semi, and the path needs to have both a .js and at least a ./ or other relative/absolute path. And I hope some of us are finally going simple, using es6 Modules and avoiding legacy workflow. Webpack is a curse .. avoid it.